# Sum up values from two lines but keeping some columns seperate

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to sum up the values in Column C for rows with same Column B value.

In my example the values for `A Dunn` and `G Birch` should be combined, with the bottom line going blank

But column A (account number) should not be combined.

```
999805  G Wilson         237.58   3281.25
9997402 A Dunn           57.80    822.04
999745  A Dunn           223.50   820.56
99928   L Watson         81.01    898.03
999277  G Birch          444.35   36151.32
999522  G Birch          2000.00  35000.32
```

Needs to be:

```
999805  G Wilson         237.58   3281.25
9997402 A Dunn           281.30   1642.60
999745  A Dunn  
99928   L Watson         81.01    898.03
999277  G Birch          2444.35  71151.64
999522  G Birch
```

Comment: Have you tried SUMIF()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Sounds like a job for [*pivot table*](https://support.office.com/en-us/Article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)!

Select your data and insert a pivot table (however it works for your version of excel on your OS). You can sum the fields in the columns and have the names listed in the rows.

<sub>click any picture to view larger size</sub>
[image]

You can also change it to `tabular` display if you need it to look more similar to what you describe:

[image]